# iOS - State restoration - Get previously restored view controller

Tags: ios, state-restoration

I have a navigation controller with several view controllers inside.

While restoring app `application(_:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder:)` method calls for each controller one by one initially for first in stack then for second and so on.
At time of restoring second view controller I need to get reference to first one (to make some connection between them).

Is there any way to get previously restored controller at this step without saving this controller somewhere in the app? (the same is about navigation controller I don't save referents to it anywhere in the app)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that only the last View Controller viewed before the app was sent to background will have its state restored by the encode/decode methods you listed above, with NSCoder.
BUT you still need to save your own data, e.g. using NSKeyedArchiver or Core Data in case the app is terminated by user, or the device reboots. This may be the best solution in your case.

See link for encodeRestorableState here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621461-encoderestorablestate

Specifically it says:

> This method is not a substitute for saving your app's data
>   structures persistently to disk. You should continue to save your
>   app's actual data to iCloud or the local file system using existing
>   techniques. This method is intended only for saving configuration
>   state or other information related to your app's user interface. You
>   should consider any data you write to the coder as purgeable and be
>   prepared for it to be unavailable during subsequent launches.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the second view controller in the first view controller's `encodeRestorableState` method. e.g.

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
     // configure and store it...
     // self.secondViewController = controller;
}

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    if (self.secondViewController) {
        [coder encodeObject:self.secondViewController forKey:kSecondViewControllerKey];
    }
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    self.secondViewController = [coder decodeObjectForKey:kSecondViewControllerKey];
}

- (void)applicationFinishedRestoringState{
    // self.secondViewController's properties are now also decoded and ready to be used
}
```

`application:viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:` can return nil for the second view controller and it will one from the storyboard for you and the reference will be what is returned in decodeObjectForKey.